# Removing features from branch before deploying

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

We gonna use GIT lab as our SCM and in initial POCs we have come across a situation like this. As in typical GITLab flow (shown in the diagram), We have Master, development and parallel feature branches as required. When all features belonging to a particular sprint done and have been merged to development branch, we branch out Release branch from development and then QA will be done on it (Release branch). After all bug fixes are applied to Release branch (when it production ready) it is supposed to merge into both development branch and master.

[image: Flow diagram]

The problem is some times, at the last moment decisions may be taken for example say Feature 'B' out of features A,B,C is not going production this time hence should be hold.

To handle a situation like the above I guess we can use git commands like Rebase/ Cherry Pick/ Reset etc.

What would be the best possible way to handle the above scenario?
Could you please explain in details as still i'm a newbie to GIT world.

Comment: I did this using revert command as a PoC. Not sure about possible issues in this approach in real circumstances. <git revert f461543 -m1>

Comment: In this image, everything can be merged to the right side, but moving code to the left side is not possible because it is alreday merged in upper branches. As already said, you can revert them, but I think you should use another workflow.